# Best way to get same number of each case of binary data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, binary

Say there's Dataframe df with columns A and B

```py
    A    B
0   1    1
1   0    1
2   0    1
3   0    1
4   1    0
```

If I want to 'equalize' the cases of column A I just have to drop one of the rows [1, 2, 3]. If I want to equalize the cases of col B then I'd have to drop three of the rows [0, 1, 2, 3].

However, if I want to equalize the cases of both columns so that the general imbalance is minimized how could I do that through pandas? Bear in mind that efficiency is very important.

Comment: You can also noticed that `[1,1]` can only be compensated by `[0,0]` and `[0,1]` by `[1,0]`.  So you can split the problem in 2 sub-problem, that are easier to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
def remove(df, col):
    #get counts of column
    s = df[col].value_counts()
    #subtract for number of removed rows
    d = s.sub(s.min())
    
    #remove filtered rows with samples
    return df.drop(df[df[col].eq(d.idxmax())].sample(d.max()).index)

df = remove(df, 'A')
print (df)
   A  B
0  1  1
1  0  1
3  0  1
4  1  0

df = remove(df, 'B')
print (df)
   A  B
3  0  1
4  1  0
```

Comment: ok, but how should this be applied for the two columns together? This solution balances only one column at a time, is there a way to apply it non sequentially, though a function that accepts a list of columns?

Comment: @Mario - It is not easy, because generally some data should not be removed...